# apache2 crashes suddenly and leaves zombie processes

Tags: apache-httpd, ps, zombie-process

I am experiencing recurring problem with my `apache` server, where after few hours/days of light usage, the `apache` process suddenly crashes and leaves zombie processes. In `ps`, I then see this:

```
root      1209 ?        Ss    0.0  1.3 Aug04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15531 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15539 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15540 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15541 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15542 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15543 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15544 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15545 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15546 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15547 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15548 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15549 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15550 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15551 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15552 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15553 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
www-data 15554 ?        Z     0.0  0.0 Aug15 [apache2] <defunct>
```

My Apache server has very light use, I can browse the server fine for a while, but then I click a link and it suddenly crashes.

I am not able to pinpoint what exactly causes the crash, seems random to me.

My server is Debian Buster, and the `apache` server is using php5 framework (for Dokuwiki). Following packages are installed:

```
apache2                2.4.38-3
apache2-bin            2.4.38-3
apache2-data           2.4.38-3
apache2-utils          2.4.38-3
libapache2-mod-php5.6  5.6.40
php5.6                 5.6.40
php5.6-cli             5.6.40
php5.6-common          5.6.40
php5.6-curl            5.6.40
php5.6-json            5.6.40
php5.6-mysql           5.6.40
php5.6-opcache         5.6.40
php5.6-readline        5.6.40
php5.6-sqlite3         5.6.40
php5.6-xml             5.6.40
```

**How can I troubleshoot this problem?**

There is no message in any of my logs (dmesg, syslog, or apache errror log)

Comment: In such a situation a core should be dumped. If no log and no clue, start from there.

Comment: @MC68020 - in which location should the core dump be stored ?

Comment: Usually the core is dumped in the current working directory of the crashing process which, generally is the present working directory of the parent at the time of the fork. If you don't know then simply find / -name core -print

Comment: @MC68020 - I have `/` mounted as read-only. Can I specify other location where coredump should be stored? Such as `/tmp/`.

Comment: / mounted read-only ??? depending on your partition scheme, this might well be the reason why your processes crash & no log & no core...